# Display UILocalNOtification Alert in iOS Till VOIP call is valid

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am developing iPhone App Using PJSIP. When i enters background mode,if i receive any call.
I am displaying UILocalNotification alert as:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

 NSString *alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NEW VOIP CALL"];
 notification.alertBody =alertBody;
 notification.alertAction = @"Answer";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

But this alert dismiss after some 4 or 5 seconds.
how to make it repeat for some more time?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:You need to Execute UIlaocationNotification Using Timer.

Solution 2: You Start Execute Notification when finish Previous notification.

Comment: My Point is Once first alert complete again you generate new alert.Once click View Button you stop all alerts thats all

Comment: As you said in solution 2 ->start executing notification when finish previous. so is there any delegate method or some notification that will tell me that previous notification has finished...can you explain with some little code demo

Comment: No. There is No delegate funtions available. Its for Just assumption we will call and create new Notification.

Comment: that is what i am asking how i will execute another notification instantly as soon as previous finishes

Answer (score 0):

The best way in your circumstances is to specify a sound to play - this can be up to 30 seconds long. This seems to keep the notification displayed for the length of the sound:

```
UILocalNotification *notification =[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSString *alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NEW VOIP CALL"];
notification.alertBody =alertBody;
notification.alertAction = @"Answer";
notification.soundName = @"56 Alarm Bell.mp3";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Comment: But this will only make sound for that time, not Alert.
I have seen in SKYPE it has been implemented.but not sure how